# nodejs new relic send status code notification

Tags: node.js, http-status-codes, newrelic, alerts

Does anyone know if it is possible to set-up notifications on new relic when a certain status code is returned form the API?

I would like to receive an email notification when a 500 status code error is returned from my API, but after searching the web and new relic's documentation along with viewing their options in the alerts dashboard, I can't seem to find anything allowing me to set this alert.

Has anyone solved this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using New Relic [Insights](https://newrelic.com/insights) and New Relic [Alerts](https://newrelic.com/alerts), you can [Create alert conditions for NRQL queries](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/alerts/new-relic-alerts/defining-conditions/create-alert-conditions-nrql-queries).

Your NRQL query would look something like:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM Transaction WHERE appName = 'YourAppName' AND `response.status` = '500'
```